# Tizen Wearable - How to find out user is sleeping?

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

I have written an app which vibrates in some conditions and The app opens with alarm API. But when the user is sleeping and they are wearing the watch it's annoying for user to vibrate. How can I have an IF condition so it checks that if user is sleeping?

Comment: Since Galaxy Watch 4, OS is changed from Tizen to Google Android Wear. You needs to add more detailed information.

Comment: Hi dear. I am writing app for GW3 and its tizen based.

Comment: I think.. you needs to investigate Samsung Health SDK. It is not Tizen feature. https://developer.samsung.com/health and https://developer.samsung.com/health-server/server/partner-only/api-reference/data-types/sleep-stage.html

Comment: thanks but i need a tizen feature

Comment: GW3 = Tizen Platform 5.5 + Samsung Additional Features, GW4 = New Android Wear + Samsung Additional Features. I think.. you need to use Samsung Health SDK to get sleep info, if possible. Because it probably requires partner privilege level.